# C#: Union of two ICollections? (equivalent of Java's addAll())

Tags: c#, syntax, coding-style

I have two `ICollection`s of which I would like to take the union. Currently, I'm doing this with a foreach loop, but that feels verbose and hideous. What is the C# equivalent of Java's `addAll()`?

Example of this problem:

```
ICollection<IDictionary<string, string>> result = new HashSet<IDictionary<string, string>>();
// ...
ICollection<IDictionary<string, string>> fromSubTree = GetAllTypeWithin(elementName, element);
foreach( IDictionary<string, string> dict in fromSubTree ) { // hacky
    result.Add(dict);
}
// result is now the union of the two sets
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [Enumerable.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) extension method:

```
result = result.Union(fromSubTree).ToList();
```

Since `result` is declared `ICollection<T>`, you'll need the `ToList()` call to convert the resulting `IEnumerable<T>` into a `List<T>` (which implements `ICollection<T>`).  If enumeration is acceptable, you could leave the `ToList()` call off, and get deferred execution (if desired).

Comment: Unfortunately, the union works as if the origin and the destiny were sets, and it overlooks repeated elements, therefore this is not the same as doing and Java `Collection.addAll()` where the collection implementation may well be a List, where repeated elements are valid.

Comment: @edalorzo In this case, you can use Enumerable.Concat instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894

Answer (score 9):

[`AddRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) appends the source list to the end of another, and may suit your needs.

```
destList.AddRange(srcList);
```

Answer (score -1):

LINQ's [Enumerable.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) will work: